# Conditionally bypass records in the .txt file in Linux by comparing fields values within the same file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, date

I need to compare two dates for each line of a `.txt` file.
If value in position 11 is equal to "02407IC" and "21100220" minus "19860220" equal to 124 years, I want to bypass this record, otherwise I want this record written to the output.

So far I tried `sed` command as follows but it only solves part of this bypassing/deleting records from the file were it finds value of `02407IC`, but I cannot figure out how to compare two dates and include that comparison into `sed` command.

```
sed -i '/02407IC/d' MARK.TXT
```

This is a sample data in the file, below is not real file but values that I am looking for in the input file. In the real input file value like '02407IC' is in position 398, lower date like '19860220' in position 265 (always present/populated) and higher date like '21100220' is in position 690, sometimes higher date can be blank/spaces:

```
19860220 02407IC 21100220
19660121 02501IC 20200218
19670301 02501IC 20200218
19880420 03105IC
```

I am trying to accomplish this with `sed` or `awk` command.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your data and include the expected output for your posted sample input. Also include anything you've tried yourself so far.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What do you mean with "position 11"? The only field with value "02407" in your sample input is line 1 column 2. Also, please specify how the input fields are separated (space, tab, ...)

Comment: Do you want to skip the empty lines, too, or are they supposed to appear in the output?

Comment: File is space delimited. Value 02407IC starts in position 11.

Comment: There is no empty lines in the file, it is just the way it shows, I will try to fix my post.

Comment: Does the date difference have to be 124 years _to the day_ in order to merit exclusion? If not, how to handle cases where it is 124 years +/- 1 ... 364 (or 365, in case of leap years) days?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "position". Is that the character position in a line or is it the space-separated field number or something else? Please simply create a small example that truly represents your real data in terms of fields having "positions" but using small values for "positions" (i.e. don't create rows that need a scroll bar to see!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
awk '!( ($2 == "02407IC") && (($3 - $1) ~ /^124....$/) )' file
```

I'm not sure what the "positions" you're referring to are but if they're character positions in each line and if field 1 starts at character position 265, field 2 at 398, and field 3 at 690 per your updated question, then you could do:

```
awk '!( (substr($0,398,7) == "02407IC") && ((substr($0,690,4) - substr($0,265,4)) == 124) )' file
```

Comment: I am only showing portion of the file, this is space delimited file, can your please show how to use fields position instead of columns $1 or $2 etc?

Comment: Thank you guys, that worked I just changed to (substr($0,398,7) == "02407IC") so it looked at all 7 bytes of the field.